# Ability to search my answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, search

I'm looking at a question I know I've answered at least once (maybe twice) before - but I have a slew of answers and I don't know which one it is. I'd love to be able to do a rudimentary search of my answers to quickly point the question poster in the right direction.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is possible - just include `user:me is:answer` in the search to search only your answers.

Comment: usually a non-issue for most folks, as most people have *far* more answers than questions.